# How to Stop the Audio After Coming Back From that audio ViewController IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, onpause

Hi I'm playing the audio file in one view controller when i  going the another view controller its still playing the audio how to pause the audio when we going back to another view controller.

```
   NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audio" ofType:@"mp3" ];
   NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
   NSError *error;
   self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&error];
  [self.audioPlayer play];
```

Please tell where i have to put the pause code for the audio when I'm going for another view controller.

Thanks.

Comment: put it in `dealloc` or `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: @Kabira can please give me the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your viewController `dealloc` method add code to stop your audioPlayer

```
 - (void)dealloc {
    if ([self.audioPlayer isPlaying])
       [self.audioPlayer stop];

     [super dealloc]; // call if you are not using ARC
 }
```

You can also put the stop audio code in `ViewWillDisappear` method if you are going deeper into heirarchy

Comment: in my m file there is no dealloc function after adding this code its showing warning method possibly missing a [super decalloc]call